# How to get UTC appended in NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

So currently I have this extension for Formatter which returns : 16/10/17 08:37:50 PM GMT but I need 16/10/17 08:37:50 PM **UTC** with UTC as appended to the nsdate. How can I achieve that?

Following is my code:

```
extension Formatter {
static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation:"UTC") as TimeZone!
    formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a zzz"
    return formatter
}()
}
```

Comment: so why do you set UTC timezone? if you want only the end different, edit string

Comment: I have tried this as well but it doesnt work : formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a UTC". Infact it gives me "16/10/17 08:37:50 PM 2017"

Comment: edit it after that, when you get your date

Comment: Thats fine...but I am looking to use it in my extension....is there a way to do it ? C# is pretty smart here...Swift seems to be lacking such things..

Comment: it will not be `DateFormatter` extension then but `Date` so you will get already formatted string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your date formatter to use `'UTC'` in place of `zzz` in your format string:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a 'UTC'"
```

You need to put string literals like `UTC` in single quotes so they are not interpreted as format characters.

Note that the above will **only** work correctly if you set the date format to the UTC time zone. If you set it to some other time zone then the output string will still end with `UTC`, which will be wrong.

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem considering that all strings generated with it and sent to the server would be valid

Comment: @LeoDabus Actually, wouldn't that formatter also convert date strings back to dates? It would assume UTC no matter what, but it should work.

Comment: As I said It should be ok as long as the string passed it is UTC time. And the date strings generated with it would also be ok

Comment: Thanks Duncan appending of UTC as a format string works.

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm changing current date to save same hour and date but only time zone changes. Try if this works for you

```
var now: Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = Const.dateFormat
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let date = Date()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a zzz"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let str = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return formatter.date(from: str)
}
```